# Flutter use PageController inside another screen

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a main page with 3 tabs where I can navigate between them via

```
  _tabController.jumpToPage(tab);
```

but when I open new screen form tab

```
      Navigator.push(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => TrainerListPage())
           );
```

I can't make navigation between tabs until screen is open and I have to do something like this:

```
 Navigator.pop(context);              
 tabStorage.tabController.jumpToPage(0);
```

where `tabStorage` is my class for keeping ref to `PageController` instance

If I will have 3 opened screen in order I have to call

```
 Navigator.pop(context)
```

three times and it has at least visual defect.
What is correct way to active it?

Comment: Why do you want to access the tabs in the `TrainerListPage()`? Are they visible?

Comment: No a tab is not visible, is it should be reason don't do it?

Comment: You've said you can't navigate between tabs until the screen is open. The question is: if they aren't visible, why would you need to navigate between them?

Comment: ok i can explain in TrainerListPage i can make a order and after submit i would like to show my orders page that is available by bottom navigation bar